# Pandas Index.droplevel() works in 0.25.3 but not in 1.2.4

Tags: pandas

Some formerly-working code fails after I migrated from 0.25.3 Pandas to 1.2.4.    Here is a reproducible example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
print(f"pandas: {pd.__version__}")
!python --version   


cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['coz',], ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma']], names=['health', 'protocol'])
index=pd.date_range(start="1jan2020", end=None, periods=5, freq="d", name="Date")
data = np.random.rand(5,3)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=index, columns=cols)

def foo(row):
    row.index = row.index.droplevel(0)
    return row['beta'] > row['alpha']

df.apply(foo, axis="columns")
```

in `0.25.3`  this worked as I wanted:

```
pandas: 0.25.3
Python 3.7.11
Date
2020-01-01    False
2020-01-02     True
2020-01-03    False
2020-01-04     True
2020-01-05    False
Freq: D, dtype: bool
```

but in `1.2.4` the same code throws an error apparently due to the `droplevel`:

```
pandas: 1.2.4
Python 3.9.4
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-4242d4f13ab1> in <module>
     15     return row['beta'] > row['alpha']
     16 
---> 17 df.apply(foo, axis="columns")

~\.conda\envs\yagi\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, raw, result_type, args, **kwds)
   7766             kwds=kwds,
   7767         )
-> 7768         return op.get_result()
   7769 
   7770     def applymap(self, func, na_action: Optional[str] = None) -> DataFrame:

~\.conda\envs\yagi\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in get_result(self)
    183             return self.apply_raw()
    184 
--> 185         return self.apply_standard()
    186 
    187     def apply_empty_result(self):

~\.conda\envs\yagi\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply_standard(self)
    274 
    275     def apply_standard(self):
--> 276         results, res_index = self.apply_series_generator()
    277 
    278         # wrap results

~\.conda\envs\yagi\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply_series_generator(self)
    288             for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
    289                 # ignore SettingWithCopy here in case the user mutates
--> 290                 results[i] = self.f(v)
    291                 if isinstance(results[i], ABCSeries):
    292                     # If we have a view on v, we need to make a copy because

<ipython-input-22-4242d4f13ab1> in foo(row)
     12 
     13 def foo(row):
---> 14     row.index = row.index.droplevel(0)
     15     return row['beta'] > row['alpha']
     16 

~\.conda\envs\yagi\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in droplevel(self, level)
   1609         levnums = sorted(self._get_level_number(lev) for lev in level)[::-1]
   1610 
-> 1611         return self._drop_level_numbers(levnums)
   1612 
   1613     def _drop_level_numbers(self, levnums: List[int]):

~\.conda\envs\yagi\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in _drop_level_numbers(self, levnums)
   1619             return self
   1620         if len(levnums) >= self.nlevels:
-> 1621             raise ValueError(
   1622                 f"Cannot remove {len(levnums)} levels from an index with "
   1623                 f"{self.nlevels} levels: at least one level must be left."

ValueError: Cannot remove 1 levels from an index with 1 levels: at least one level must be left.
```

What seems to be happening is in `1.2.4` the `droplevel` seems to be accumulating!  The first row passed into `apply()`, has a 2-level index.  But the second row passed into `apply()` has a single-level index, and this is where the error screams. This I don't understand at all.

Here is same toy w/ a print diagnostic

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
print(f"pandas: {pd.__version__}")
!python --version   


cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['coz',], ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma']], names=['health', 'protocol'])
index=pd.date_range(start="1jan2020", end=None, periods=5, freq="d", name="Date")
data = np.random.rand(5,3)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=index, columns=cols)

def foo(row):
    print(f"\nROW: {row}  END")
    row.index = row.index.droplevel(0)
    return row['beta'] > row['alpha']

foo  = df.apply(foo, axis="columns")
```

correct output:

```
pandas: 0.25.3
Python 3.7.11

ROW: health  protocol
coz     alpha       0.054421
        beta        0.922885
        gamma       0.843888
Name: 2020-01-01T00:00:00.000000000, dtype: float64  END

ROW: health  protocol
coz     alpha       0.962803
        beta        0.827594
        gamma       0.260147
Name: 2020-01-02T00:00:00.000000000, dtype: float64  END

ROW: health  protocol
coz     alpha       0.680902
        beta        0.124468
        gamma       0.960604
Name: 2020-01-03T00:00:00.000000000, dtype: float64  END

ROW: health  protocol
coz     alpha       0.133331
        beta        0.664735
        gamma       0.623440
Name: 2020-01-04T00:00:00.000000000, dtype: float64  END

ROW: health  protocol
coz     alpha       0.984164
        beta        0.578701
        gamma       0.538993
Name: 2020-01-05T00:00:00.000000000, dtype: float64  END
Date
2020-01-01     True
2020-01-02    False
2020-01-03    False
2020-01-04     True
2020-01-05    False
Freq: D, dtype: bool
```

failing output:

```
pandas: 1.2.4
Python 3.9.4

ROW: health  protocol
coz     alpha       0.374974
        beta        0.137263
        gamma       0.494556
Name: 2020-01-01 00:00:00, dtype: float64  END

ROW: protocol
alpha    0.591057
beta     0.560530
gamma    0.183457
Name: 2020-01-02 00:00:00, dtype: float64  END
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-bbef1b39f13a> in <module>
     16     return row['beta'] > row['alpha']
     17 
---> 18 foo  = df.apply(foo, axis="columns")

...

ValueError: Cannot remove 1 levels from an index with 1 levels: at least one level must be left.
```

========

So I can fix this by operating on a `.copy()` of the row,  but this feels like a hack. I don't understand why the code has started working in this way after the version change.

```
def foo(row):
    #print(f"\nROW: {row}  END")
    row=row.copy()
    row.index = row.index.droplevel(0)
    return row['beta'] > row['alpha']
```

Comment: df.coz['beta'] > df.coz['alpha'] ?

Answer (score 0):

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/gotchas.html#mutating-with-user-defined-function-udf-methods

Do not mutate with user-defined-methods like `.apply()`.  I was just lucky that it worked in 0.25.3....